# Convert a string to date in java and check if is in daylight savings for America/NewYork timezone

Tags: java

I have a string in format `MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss am`

I need to convert this to date and at the same time I have to check if this date/time is in daylight savings time for America/New York time zone.

My code is always returning `false`.

```
Date calculatedDate;
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy hh:mm:ss a"); 

public void checkIfDateIsDST() throws Exception {   
        TimeZone timezoneone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New York");

    String datetime1 = "12/10/14 3:03:45 pm";
        try {
            calculatedDate = df.parse(datetime1);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
        }

        TimeZone timezoneone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New York");

        System.out.println("In daylight time:" +timezoneone.getTimeZone("America/NewYork").inDaylightTime(calculatedDate));
}
```

Comment: What do you want the answer to be if a particular local time is in standard *and* daylight saving time (because it's repeated when the clocks go back)?

Comment: Note that it's probably not parsing because you've specified "hh" but you're only providing "3". Try "h" instead.

Comment: Hi Jon..Yes I want the answer to be in boolean state whether the date is in daylight saving time or not.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. A given local date/time can be: a) skipped because the clocks moved forward; b) only in standard time; c) only in daylight saving time; d) in both standard and daylight saving time because the clocks moved backward. That's four different answers; a `boolean` only gives you two options. You need to think about what you want those for answers to map to.

Comment: I am new to these time zones. May be I am not understanding your question as well as my requirement. What I really want to check if that date/time falls in day light saving time or not. There is an interface in which I will get the date in America/new York format and I can change the time zone to Pacific/Yap. I will have to verify the new date/time according to new time zone. It could be +14 hours or +15 hours depending on daylight saving. That is why I want to know the day light saving status for a date.

Comment: I'm not sure how many times I can say the same thing. What would you want the answer to be for November 2nd 2014 at 1.30am? That local time occurs twice... once before the clocks go back, and once after they go back. (Because the time goes from 2am back to 1am.)